# Fetching in Next.js , I get 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, next.js, http-post, http-status-code-404, fetch-api

I'm working on a project in Next.js using TypeScript trying to solve this problem but I couldn't do it. Please help me.

I'm just trying to send data to an API but all I got is 404 Not Found on the browser (inspect), I test the endpoint on postman it works correctly.

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const RegisterForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    c_password: '',
  });

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    console.log(formData);
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://event-reg.app/flutter_test/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Registration successful!');
      } else {
        console.error('Registration failed:', response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className="max-w-md mx-auto mt-8 p-6 bg-white rounded shadow-md"
    >
      <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Register</h2>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label className="block mb-2" htmlFor="name">
          Name
        </label>
        <input
          className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formData.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label className="block mb-2" htmlFor="email">
          Email
        </label>
        <input
          className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formData.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label className="block mb-2" htmlFor="password">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={formData.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label className="block mb-2" htmlFor="c_password">
          Confirm Password
        </label>
        <input
          className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded"
          type="password"
          name="c_password"
          value={formData.c_password}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="w-full bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 transition duration-300"
      >
        Register
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default RegisterForm;
```

Comment: I would have thought this would cause CORS issue but not 404. In any cases, you should call the external API from a NextJS API route (or server component) to avoid issues.